# How to create system variables initialized by separate line of input

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, xargs

I have a list of files, which is given for instance by `find . -name file.*`

```
./file.a
./dir1/dir2/file.b
./dir1/dir3/file.c
./file.d
./file.e

...
```

How to automatically create variables as fallows:

```
F1=./file.a
F2=./dir1/dir2/file.b
F3=./dir1/dir3/file.c
F4=./file.d
F5=./file.e

...
```

I guess some smart combination of sed/awk/xargs will do the job.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: What's the logic for 
`F1=../../file.a
F2=../dir1/dir2/file.b
F3=../dir1/dir3/file.c
F4=./file.d
F5=./file.e`

I mean, how do you get `../../` for one and `./` for the other?

Comment: Then kev has the answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ F=(`find . -name 'file.*'`)
$ for((i=1;i<=${#F};i++)); do eval "F$i='${F[$i]}'"; done
```

Comment: +1. Will break on any files with spaces, but nice and compact.

Answer (score 1):

perl -e "@files = qx(find . -name file.*);"

Comment: maybe best way is this:
perl -e "map{FooFunction($_);}qx(find . -name file.*);"

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
find . -name 'file.*' | sed = | sed 'N;s/^\(.*\)\n/F\1=/' >/tmp/source
. /tmp/source
```

Comment: Oo sed more difficult to understand, than perl :)